# Handling multiple sub-urls in Django's url.py file

Tags: django

In my djang urls pattern file, I'd like to hold a bunch of sub-url's but I don't want to make it ugly.

I have a file which handles all of my Ajax requests (it outputs different JSON files depending on the request it gets.

example (in my url.py):
in the form: (url, maps to)
`(ajax/do_a,  ajax.do_a)
ajax/do_b, ajax.do_b)
ajax/do_c, ajax.do_c)
ajax/do_d, ajax.do_d)`

these are all sub-urls, eg.
mywebsite.com/ajax/do_a
mywebsite.com/ajax/do_b
etc.

Basically do_a,do_b,do_c,and do_d are all different request handlers sitting in the same same in the "ajax.py" file. I really don't want to be filling up my urls.py file with all of these urls for ajax requests. I was thinking of move this so that I only have
ajax/
in my url.py file and then somehow parse the ajax/ request url in my request handler (in the ajax.py file) so I can see what string came after the "ajax/". I'm not sure how to do this or if this would be a good idea to do this....Could anyone offer some advice? thanks :)

Comment: I wouldn't call those sub-urls, and you may want to look at [named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) or [capturing text in urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

Comment: do all the views need to be unique views or can you just pass the `do_a` part of `www.example.com/ajax/do_a` to the same view?

Comment: @j_syk I don't understand your question

Comment: ok, let's you have a url of do_a, and your view is ajax.do_a, and also another url of do_b and view ajax.do_b. Do ajax.do_a and ajax.do_b do the same thing except use different data? or do the view functions need to be completely different. If they do the same thing, just with different inputs and outputs, I think Jack's answer should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a dispatcher view for handling these.  For example, in your urls.py:

```
(r'^ajax/do_(?P<do_token>(\d+))/$', 'do_dispatcher', {}, "di_dispatcher"),
```

Then, give yourself a view to handle it:

```
def do_a(request):
    pass
def do_b(request):
    pass
def do_c(request):
    pass

DO_LOOKUP = {
    'a' = do_a,
    'b' = do_b,
    'c' = do_c,
}

def do_dispatch(request, do_token):
    do_func = DO_LOOKUP.get(do_token, None)
    if do_func is None:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("No do could be found for token '%s'!" % do_token)
    else:
        return do_func(request)
```